# Scann several projects in Sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I am using sonarQube 6.3 ( and will migrate to 6.4) with sonar scanner 3.0.0.702-windows to scan C# code.

I know that to scan a project with sonarQube we need to define a properties file then execute sonarscanner. Nevertheless, when it comes to too many projects, it's not easy to do it.

I would like to know if there is a user interface or a more visible way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For C# you should be using the [SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild). This scanner takes most of the required information from your solution file. The remaining values should be provided on the command line, like so:

```
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"org.sonarqube:sonarqube-scanner-msbuild" /n:"Project Name" /v:"1.0"
MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end
```